# Git format-patch with deleted files that were placed back later

Tags: git, format-patch

So one of my colleagues accidentally deleted some files that they thought weren't necessary, but later found out that they were necessary. We now are trying to make a patch file for all changes between two commits, but these files that were deleted and re-added also show up in the patch file. This results in a patch file of nearly 1GB. Is it possible to ignore these files, since these files didn't actually change between the 2 commits?

Comment: How did you create the patch? `format-patch` creates patches for all the commits, how specifically did you instruct it to avoid the commits that deleted the files? Perhaps you would be better of rebasing and squashing?

Comment: I don’t get what the patch file is for. Why not just restore the files and commit now and carry on? Or if the goal is to change history, restore the files and commit and splice that commit into the history?

Comment: i used `git format-patch <first commit>..<last commit> --stdout > mypatch.patch` to create the patch.

Comment: So that patch will contain all the commits in that range, including those that delete the files and then later re-add them. However, deal with @matt's comment first, **why** are you doing this? Can't you simply restore the deleted files and move on? Or, if you've already restored the files (which I assume "re-added" means), why do you need to do anything?

Comment: This repo is a stripped version of another repo. To import the changes made in this repo in the other repo, the people from that repo requested a patch file.

Comment: A patch file is not "the difference between point A and B", it is the commits from A to B, which will include your deletes and then re-adds. You need to clean up the repository first then, to get rid of those deletions.

Comment: @chrisstar123 : if you want to generate "a patch to go from A to B in one go", use `git diff -p A B`, not `git format-patch`. Look at the docs on `git diff` for extra options.